# SQL Developer script output to datagrid

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-scripts

In Oracle SQL Developer, I can get simple query results returned in the 'Query Results' grid, but if I need to use variable in script, I need to use the 'Run Script' option and my results show up in 'Script Output' window, and I can't export it to csv format. Here is my sample code:

```
    var CatCode char(5) ;
    exec :CatCode := 'ZK';
    SELECT * FROM Products WHERE CategoryCode = :CatCode;
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go you can run this one to be ensure. it's running.

```
    set colsep ,     -- separate columns with a comma
    set pagesize 0   -- No header rows
    set trimspool on -- remove trailing blanks
    set headsep off  -- this may or may not be useful...depends on your headings.
    set linesize X   -- X should be the sum of the column widths
    set numw X       -- X should be the length you want for numbers (avoid scientific notation on IDs)

    spool C:\Users\**direcotory**\sql\Test1.csv; --this is file path to save data
    var CatCode char(5) ;
    exec :CatCode := 'ZK';
    SELECT * FROM Products WHERE CategoryCode = :CatCode;
    spool off;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `/*csv*/` to your query, the tool will bring back the output in CSV automatically when executed as a script (F5).

Or use a substitution variable instead. &Var vs :Var, run with F9, SQLDev will prompt you for the value.

```
VAR stcode CHAR(2);

EXEC :stcode := 'NC';

SELECT /*csv*/
    *
  FROM
    untappd
 WHERE
    venue_state   =:stcode;
```

[image]

Or to go straight to the grid so you can use can use the Grid Export feature.

```
SELECT
    *
  FROM
    untappd
 WHERE
    venue_state   =:stcode2;
```

Execute with Ctrl+Enter or F9

Supply the input parameter in the pop up dialog, click OK.

Shazaam.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, it works but I need it in data grid. My query returns 50K+ records and I need to export it to csv. I dont have enough rights to create procedure so I have to do it in worksheet only. Is there any other solution to export query results into csv?

Comment: There are tons of variable in my actual query and most of the time it will have default value. So I don't want any popup window for values rather I would change in script and run.

Comment: @mak101 so don't do that then, run it as a script, use the CSV comment, and spool it as a file. it'll run quicker and in fewer steps.

Comment: @mak101 you can spool 50k records to CSV using my solution...or with slight variations

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @thatjeffsmith and Paras, spool option gave me new direction and it worked. I slightly changed your code and it works great.

```
var CatCode char(5) ;
exec :CatCode := 'ZK';
set feedback off;
SET SQLFORMAT csv;
spool "c:\temp\spoolTest.csv"
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE CategoryCode = :CatCode;
spool off;
SET SQLFORMAT;
set feedback on;
```

Comment: I have one more question, How do I spool to dynamic file? I want to add CatCode in my file name, I tried:

    var csvFile varchar2(100)
    exec :csvFile := 'c:\temp\MyCSV_' ||  trim(:CatCode) || '.csv';
    spool csvFile
But it does not work. Any tips?